# How to impl ops::Deref for an struct wrapped in a Mutex

Tags: rust

When using a `Arc<Mutex<>>` wrapper for a struct, is it possible to deref the wrapper into one of the internal structs fields? In this case I want to deref my `PersonWrapper` struct into a `String` from the inner `PersonStruct` "name" field.

```rust
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

pub struct PersonWrapper{
  inner: Arc<Mutex<Person>>
}

impl PersonWrapper{
    pub fn new(name: String, age: i32,)->Self{
        PersonWrapper{
            inner: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Person::new(name, age)))
        }
    }
}

pub struct Person{
    name: String,
    age: i32, 
}

impl Person{
    pub fn new(name: String, age: i32)->Self{
        Person{
            name,
            age,
        }
    }
}

impl std::ops::Deref for PersonWrapper{
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.inner.into_inner().unwrap().name
        // &self.inner.lock().unwrap().node_id.clone()
    }
}


fn main(){
  let wrapped_person = PersonWrapper::new(String::from("Zondo"), 45);
  assert_eq!(*wrapped_person, String::from("Zondo"));
}
```

gives errors:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
           &self.inner.into_inner().unwrap().name
            ^--------------------------------^^^^^
            ||
            |temporary value created here
            returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Arc`
            &self.inner.into_inner().unwrap().name
             ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Mutex<Person>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58ea01b920cc377ca69fa9a9e498291d)

Comment: Ignoring the `Arc`/`Mutex` problem, implementing `Deref` for a `Person` into its name I would consider to be an abuse of the trait. It's not clear why a person should behave as if it were a string and allow things like `person.is_empty()`.

Comment: I see. I guess I've seen it used like that before, but maybe that doesn't make sense in this context. I was just hoping to get easy access to the ```name``` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to provide convenient access to a part of data behind a `Mutex`, combining the locking and "projecting" (narrowing to a field), you can use the `Mutex` from the [parking_lot](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/) crate. Among many other optimizations and improvements, it offers `MutexGuard`. For example:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use parking_lot::{Mutex, MutexGuard, MappedMutexGuard};

pub struct PersonWrapper {
    inner: Arc<Mutex<Person>>,
}

impl PersonWrapper {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: i32) -> Self {
        PersonWrapper {
            inner: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Person::new(name, age))),
        }
    }
    
    pub fn name(&self) -> MappedMutexGuard<String> {
        MutexGuard::map(self.inner.lock(), |p| &mut p.name)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `name()` as if it were a locked mutex that only held the `name` part of the `Person`:

```
let wrapped_person = PersonWrapper::new("Zondo".to_owned(), 45);
assert_eq!(&*wrapped_person.name(), "Zondo");
*wrapped_person.name() = "Mondo".to_owned();
assert_eq!(&*wrapped_person.name(), "Mondo");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19aa05a968b19bc456a96259de56b444)